# read usb barcode scanner data behind the scenes(form minimize state )

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner

I am developing a barcode track keeping form in `c#` , I am using `AGROX USD barcode scanner`.

I would like to know if there is a possible way to read the punched barcode when my form is in minimize state or say it is running in background.

At present the punched data gets printed where the cursor is focused. I want to store that punched data at my specified location say in my form. I have heard that reading USB port can help me but how to do , i have no idea as I am new to this.

Any help would be appreciated great 
thanks

Comment: Most barcode scanners emulate a keyboard so that no special software is required to use it. I think you need to set it to a different mode to use it differently, perhaps emulating a serial port. Look at the scanner documentation.

Comment: by your word "At present", where is the current code ? community cant dream the way out ....

Comment: can i read inputed data from the usb port

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mark Ransom, you should look for a different APi for your scanner.

If there is no other api, you could listen after [Global keyboard events](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C), and then assume that 13 (depends on barcode type) consecutive numbers entered within 100 ms is a scan from you keyboard.

By only accepting numbers entered really fast, you can filter out people entering numbers in other applications manually.